# Get Parent Tables Parent Table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with Sharepiont and the code it spits out is messy at best.

I have the id of a div inside a table which is inside another table and I need to get at the parent tables parent table.

Here is the JsFiddle I am working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/BpnNJ/2/

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("div").parents("table").parents("table")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Try it on the JsFiddle and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code & found something interesting about your question. As your question you need to have parents parent table, so I've here is the method for that

```
$("div").closest("table").closest("table").attr('class');
```

Here is an full working example 
[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/baigmirzashakir/6txP7/)